# wso2 Rest response from custom code

Tags: rest, wso2

I have the following usecase, where I have to create a rest url dynamically using the properties. For that I have created a custom Mediator which reads the properties and creates calls the backend service. 
I am having an issue on how to send the response back to the user. It is an xml format. But I need to parse the xml and just send the text. For that I am using PayloadFactory. I am attaching my code here, can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

```
        <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="tririgaProxy" context="/services">
       <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/employee">
          <inSequence>
             <sequence key="tririgaConf"/>
             <property name="triUser" expression="get-property('triUser')"/>
             <property name="triPass" expression="get-property('triPass')"/>
             <property name="triURL" expression="get-property('triURL')"/>
             <property name="triWfName" expression="get-property('triPeople.database.employee.wfName')"/>
             <class name="com.wso2.tririga.mediator.IncomingMediator"/>
             <payloadFactory media-type="text">
                <format><![CDATA[$1]</format>
                <args>
                   <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/status/text()"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
          </inSequence>
       </resource>
```

## Java Class:

```
package com.wso2.tririga.mediator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;
import org.apache.synapse.util.PayloadHelper;

public class IncomingMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(IncomingMediator.class);

    @Override
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext msgContext) {
        String triUser = String.valueOf(msgContext.getProperty("triUser"));
        String triPass = String.valueOf(msgContext.getProperty("triPass"));
        String triURL = String.valueOf(msgContext.getProperty("triURL"));
        String triWfName = String.valueOf(msgContext.getProperty("triWfName"));

        try {
            URI uri = new URIBuilder(triURL)
                    .addParameter("USERNAME", triUser)
                    .addParameter("PASSWORD", triPass)
                    .addParameter("ioName", triWfName).build();
            log.info("URI: "+uri.toString());
            String response = execute(uri);         
            PayloadHelper.setTextPayload(msgContext, convertToXML(response));           
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            log.error("Error while creating URI", e);           
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static String execute(URI uri) {
        String responseBody = null;
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet();
            ((HttpRequestBase) get).setURI(uri);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        return "Successful".equalsIgnoreCase(responseStr) ? "RetCode=C;Message=Success" : "RetCode=F;Message=Failed because Itegration Exception";
                    } else {
                        throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                    }
                }
            };          
            try {
                responseBody = httpclient.execute(get, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                httpclient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return responseBody;
    }

    private static String convertToXML(String response){
        return"<status>"+response+"</status>";      
    }

}
```

I dont get any response back from here.

Comment: Try adding MessageType property to text/plain and respond mediator after payloadFactory mediator in your configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but it did not work for me. I added the following in my code:
 <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/> 
Added <respond/> after the PayLoadFactory.

Comment: You are missing to add respond mediator(   <respond/>)  after the property.

Comment: Not sure if I missed what you said, but I have added respond mediator after the payloadFactory mediator.
Here is the snippet
<payloadFactory media-type="text">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="/status/text()"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
         <respond/>
I am fairly new to WSO2, so I might not be understanding this correctly.

Comment: Yes.You have done it correctly.Did you get any errors in ESB log ?

Comment: No I cannot see any errors in the logs console. Just to let you know. My Java code return a string like this <status>response</status> which my payloadfactory mediator is parsing. Is the parsing correct?

Comment: Can anyone advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to transform the response message you need to do the payload transformation in the **out sequence** of the api.

currently what you are doing is transforming the message in the **in sequence.**